# Using get with environment variable namespace

Tags: environment-variables, list

I want to use `get` with the environment variable namespace, so instead of this in the *global* namespace:

```
let vim_data_dir = get(g:, 'vim_data_dir', "default value if not set")
```

Something like this, in the `$` or *environment variable* namespace:

```
let $VIM_DATA_DIR = get($, 'VIM_DATA_DIR', "default value if not set")
```

The help says that the first parameter to `get` is a list. How do I get all environment variables as a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, you could simply use the good old `exists()`

```
:let foo = exists('$FOO') ? $FOO : 'default'
```

There is also `empty()`, IMO it only makes sense if you want to undefine environment variables from within Vim. Indeed, as `:unlet $FOO` isn't possible, yet, we have to use `:let $FOO=''`

To obtain all environment variables, you could use `getcompletion()` on recent vim versions. The latest version of my [obtain-whatever function](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib) looks like this:

```
" Function: lh#command#matching_askvim(what, lead) {{{3
if exists('*getcompletion')
  function! lh#command#matching_askvim(what, lead) abort
    return getcompletion(a:lead, a:what)
  endfunction
else
  function! lh#command#matching_askvim(what, lead) abort
    let cleanup = lh#on#exit()
          \.register('delcom LHAskVimMatchingCompletion')
    try
      exe 'command! -complete='.a:what.' -nargs=* LHAskVimMatchingCompletion :echo "<args>"'
      if exists('*getcmdline')
        call cleanup
              \.restore('g:cmds')
              \.restore_buffer_mapping('?', 'c')
              \.restore_mapping_and_clear_now('<c-a>', 'c')
        cnoremap <buffer> <expr> ? s:register()
        function! s:register()
          let g:cmds = split(getcmdline(), ' ')[1:]
          return ''
        endfunction
        silent! exe "norm :LHAskVimMatchingCompletion ".a:lead."\<c-a>?"
        return g:cmds
      else
        " The following may lead to problem with unescaped quotes => use
        " getcmdline() when available
        silent! exe "norm! :LHAskVimMatchingCompletion ".a:lead."\<c-a>\"\<home>let\ cmds=\"\<cr>"
        return split(cmds, ' ')[1:]
      endif
    finally
      call cleanup.finalize()
    endtry
  endfunction
endif
```

(It's complex in order to support mappings as well)

To obtain all environment variables, you can then use: `echo lh#command#matching_askvim('environment', '')`

Answer (score 1):

`$VIM_DATA_DIR` already gives you the environment variable, so you can do

```
let $VIM_DATA_DIR = !empty($VIM_DATA_DIR) ? $VIM_DATA_DIR : "default"
```

If you really need all environment variables take a look at [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11192777/52817):

```
function! Env()
    redir => s
    sil! exe "norm!:ec$\<c-a>'\<c-b>\<right>\<right>\<del>'\<cr>"
    redir END
    return split(s)
endfunction
```